# Google OAuth UWP App - Close Browser Tab

Tags: google-chrome, xamarin.forms, uwp, google-oauth

Using [this example here](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp) works well for me to add Google authentication to my UWP app (more specifically, to my UWP project in a Xamarin Forms app). However, after authenticating and automatically going back to the app via the redirect URL, the browser tab that was opened for the google log-in remains opened (it gets navigated to google.com and doesn't close after switching back to the app). Anyone know how to close it (just that tab, of course) automatically?

Comment: Are you solved this prob?